# JSON Hierarchy : Hesitating on how to implement it

Tags: javascript, json, hierarchy

I'm actually building a website where I need to display a hierarchy and I've the constraint to build the latter with JSON.

So before implementing anything, two possibilities comes to my mind for the hierarchy and I can't figure out which one will be the most efficient for my project.

### Objective

I have to display on a webpage, using HTML5 BoilerPlate, a whole hierarchy represented in the `dico_tree` field. I'll have to parse this one with JavaScript in order to get all the data it contains.

***Constraints***

- Items can have one or no parent (represented by null).
- Items can have multiple or no children.
- I'll have to find the fastest way possible each unique item in order to have a quick display on my webpage.

## Possibilities I've thought about

`Possibility 1`

```
{
    "dico_name" : "Dictionary",
    "version" : "1",
    "dico_tree" : [
       {"ID" : 1,"parent" : null,"children" : [2]},
       {"ID" : 2, "parent" : 1, "children": [3,4]},
       {"ID" : 3, "parent" : 2, "children": null},
       {"ID" : 4, "parent" : 2, "children": null},
       {"ID" : 5,"parent" : null,"children" : [6]},
       {"ID" : 6, "parent" : 5, "children": [7]},
       {"ID" : 7, "parent" : 6, "children": null}],
    "custom_translations_list" : [
       {"TRANSLATION_ID" : 1, "CUSTOM_TRANSLATION_ID" : 12}
}
```

`Possibility 2`

```
{
  "dico_name" : "Dictionary",
  "version" : "1",
  "dico_tree" : [
    {"ID" : 1,"parent" : null,"children" : [
      {
        "ID" : 2, "parent" : 1, "childen": [
        {
          "ID" : 3, "parent" : 2, "children": null
        },
        {
          "ID" : 4, "parent" : 2, "children": null
        }
        ]
      }
    ]},
    {"ID" : 5,"parent" : null,"children" : [
      {
        "ID" : 6, "parent" : 5, "childen": [
        {
          "ID" : 7, "parent" : 6, "children": null
        }
        ]
      }
    ]}
  ],
  "custom_translations_list" : [
    {"TRANSLATION_ID" : 1, "CUSTOM_TRANSLATION_ID" : 12},
  ]
}
```

I'm up to add any precision if you need some !

Thanks for your time and help in advance :).

Answer (score 0):

Does `disco_tree` have to be an array? Making it an object would allow you to access any item in O(1). Also, if an item with no children has an empty array `[]` instead of `null`, you can save yourself some annoying null pointer exceptions.

```
"dico_tree" : {
       1 : {"ID" : 1, "parent" : null, "children" : [2] },
       2 : {"ID" : 2, "parent" : 1, "children": [3,4] },
       3 : {"ID" : 3, "parent" : 2, "children": [] },
       4 : {"ID" : 4, "parent" : 2, "children": [] },
       5 : {"ID" : 5, "parent" : null, "children" : [6]},
       6 : {"ID" : 6, "parent" : 5, "children": [7] },
       7 : {"ID" : 7, "parent" : 6, "children": [] }
},
```

Comment: No it hasn't to be an array, but I thought it would be more convenient for it to be an array, allowing me to use the numeric indexes without having to add it in front as you did. I started building it, and picked the second possibility because, in my opinion, the hierarchy is represented in a clearer way and it passes greatly my tests at the moment, even if there are null values on some children. Do you think it will causes me trouble later ? Knowing I use JS and "for_each" loops on the children attribute.

Comment: Nothing will cause you trouble as long as your data structure is consistent and you know your way around it. If your tests pass, and you can find everything in your structure simply and quickly enough without any errors, then it's fine.